# How to call multiple independent jquery ajax calls in parallel and call function when they all finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to call multiple independent jquery ajax calls in parallel and then call a function when its done. I saw this example here

http://collaboradev.com/2014/01/27/understanding-javascript-promises-in-jquery/

But I just want to know if it is calling them in parallel or in sequence (chaining them)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$.when() is similar to Promise.all(). The promises you pass it will all run asynchronously and your .done() won't run until they all complete. There is not a guaranteed order of resolution of the promises you pass.

Comment: But does it make all the ajax requests at the same time?

Comment: It works just like any js code, executing from top to bottom. The calls will be executed in the order you put them, but because they are asynchronous they won't necessarily finish in the order they started.

Comment: Sorry what I meant to ask is, will it make the calls from left to right? when they finish doesn't matter. but as long as the second call doesn't happen when the first finishes.

Comment: Ajax calls are async. That means they get pushed onto the stack to run as soon as there is availability. None of them will wait for the other to finish before they start, unless you force that flow by nesting the calls.